# PHP - Get rid of notation

Tags: php, math, programming-languages, int, notation

I have a very large number here but I cannot get rid of the notation. I want it to display only numbers instead of 
"4.8357032784585E+24 - 77"

I tried (int)$variable but it didn't help. Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`number_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

```
echo number_format($variable, 0, '.', '');
```